# Perform a select query based on a previous query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to perform two queries on a number of tables. The first query joins several tables and uses several conditions. It is something like this:

```
SELECT items.id, tableX.colA, tableY.colB ...
FROM items
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON ...
    LEFT JOIN table3 ON ...
    ...
WHERE {some conditions are true}
```

The second query is a simple query, but depends on the result of the first one. I would like to select all rows related to the previous query by their id. So it should be something like this

```
SELECT meta_name, meta_value FROM items_meta WHERE item IN ({LIST OF IDS FROM PREVIOUS QUERY})
```

The two queries will be used for different purposes so they cannot be merged into one.

I've been thinking of storing the result of the first query in a temporary table, then JOIN the second query to it. But I can't seem to find a decent way of returning the rows of the first query and putting the IDs into a temporary table.

All contributions are greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: your ID's must be join with comma(,)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to design your `ID's` like i use in the query. You can use the `join` function of PHP here.

**Query**

```
SELECT meta_name, meta_value FROM items_meta WHERE item IN ('4', '8', '11')
```

Comment: Yes but thats not actually helping him do that now is it. This is more of a comment than an answer!

Comment: As he/ she mention `The first query joins several tables`. So i suggest to JOIN the IDs.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. This is the current implementation. The join() function wouldn't work because the result consists of several columns. So I'm currently using PHP's foreach() function to form the ID list. I was thinking there might be a more appropriate way in doing this in SQL without PHP

Comment: @elSama, what you mean about the join?? I mean a join function of PHP. If you need to done with SQL then wait.

Comment: @FrayneKonok, that's what I'm referring to as well. I'm actually using its alias implode(). I'm using the foreach loop to create a list, then use implode later. It just might be what you're referring to

Comment: @FrayneKonok, your contribution has made me realise that I was on the right path. Jumping to PHP and back to SQL made me feel as though I was doing it wrongly. Really appreciate your input

Answer (score 3):

Here are two options:

- Store the results of the first query in a (temporary) table.  Then use this table in the final query.
- Store the results of the first query in the application, and then construct the `IN` list.

Or, just combine the queries using:

```
SELECT meta_name, meta_value
FROM items_meta
WHERE item IN (SELECT items.id
               FROM table1
                    LEFT JOIN table2 ON ...
                    LEFT JOIN table3 ON ...
                     ...
               WHERE {some conditions are true}
              );
```

Comment: Sir, is `tableX.colA, tableY.colB ...` not a problem at this purpose??

Comment: ... or just construct a proper query

Comment: So, that's *three* options then ;)

Comment: The main issue with this approach is that the first query is very expensive and I wouldn't want to repeat it in the second query. Since this will create so much overhead.

Comment: Actually Gordon, would that inner query work that way, as its returning more columns than the IN requires. _Interested to know_

Comment: I also ask for it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly . . . Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not doing the second query via SQL but doing it over PHP. After having performed your first query, you would then save the selected information into an array:

```
//MySQL (PDO):
$sql = "...";//your first SQL code
$sqlPrepared = $conn->prepare($sql);
$sqlPrepared->execute();

$rows = $sqlPrepared->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

At this point you would have an array with the information you need to do your second algorithm/query/filter/whatever hahah. If you were to place it in another table, you would have to create a new table with all the new columns which is a bit more tedious. Instead you can:

```
$new_rows = array();
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
  /*here you check if the row has the values you seek in the 'item' column
  WHERE item IN ({LIST OF IDS FROM PREVIOUS QUERY})*/
  if (($row['item']== '4')||($row['item']== '10')||...)
  {
    array_push($new_rows, $row);
  }
}
```

Now you have the $new_rows array which you can use to inspect your selected information with something like:

```
print_r($new_rows);
```

Let me know if this is what you were looking for!

Comment: I think this approach is similar to that suggested by @FrayneKanok. And that's what I'll be using

Comment: @elSama Glad I could help. If you have any doubts in how to implement it, don't hesitate in posting a question here in the comments :)